# Explicitly infer object as readonly

Tags: typescript, object, generics, types

I have a function which takes in an object

```
declare function f<T extends object>(body: T): any;

f({
  type: "object",
})
```

Function signature looks like this:

```
function f<{
    type: string;
}>(body: {
    type: string;
}): any
```

But i expect it to be:

```
function f<{
    type: "object";
}>(body: {
    type: "object";
}): any
```

without actually using as const when passing the object.

Is there any way I can infer the object type explicitly as readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to indicate a preference for [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)-like inference:

```
declare function f<const T extends object>(body: T): any;

f({ type: "object" })
/* function f<{ readonly type: "object"; }>(
    body: { readonly type: "object"; }
): any */
```

Here the type of the object literal `{ type: "object" }` has been inferred as `{ readonly type: "object" }`, without needing an explicit `as const`.

Thus the `type` property is *both* [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) *and* a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

The question as asked doesn't seem to distinguish between `readonly` and literal properties, so I guess it doesn't matter much here.  But note that in general `readonly` properties don't need to be of literal types and literal typed properties don't need to be `readonly`:

```
const readonlyNotLiteral: { readonly a: string } = { a: "abc" };
readonlyNotLiteral.a = "def"; // error
readonlyNotLiteral.a = "abc"; // error

const literalNotReadonly: { a: "abc" } = { a: "abc" };
literalNotReadonly.a = "def"; // error
literalNotReadonly.a = "abc"; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4w8BnDeAFXhAA8MRVgT4cAjAK3AwD4AKVnMACeALkoBKMVFRCA3ACh5iXgG94GIQAcQYgERtOmXfAC+4+QHoAVEjSZc+RATVwowPBCHqtO+Po5curKmfPLw4fACwmIuIG4eXhraegaBwSbykvDSXlYWisSoZPCu7qieAHI4GAAyWPQwUBAxJXFlntliZDBYqADmpvAAvPBqUHpQrGDGJgqlCVW19SCNEAB0UMN+oIhB8BYW1DAwODDy8+VCi3UNTRtbupPTwQdHJ2fyhcUQy6uLAEptBItcZ+J4zLZjCZTGYKH63CAAoGXe4jXQ7PavFbveTwlZNJHxFGbNHgl6HHAAaygQiAA)